# table view in Model View- ViewModel architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

table view in objective-c is:-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView
{
    return 1;
}

// number of row in the section, I assume there is only 1 row
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

// the cell will be returned to the tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but 
    JSCustomCell *cell = (JSCustomCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[JSCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    // Just want to test, so I hardcode the data
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = @"Testing";

    return cell;
}
```

but how to do according to the Model view- viewmodel(MVVM) architecture in objective-c?

Comment: are you using same tableview and its data source in many places?

Comment: the most important question is: do you know (=do you have the knowledge of) how MVVM would look in an iOS project? because your question indicates the answer _"no"_; so I think, you should take a look at how the data bindings would work on general in MVVM then there is a chance to talk about where you might've been stuck at during applying than in an iOS project – __tl;dr;__ your question is just too broad in its current form, because a lot of tutorials are available around the net.

Comment: You don't seem to have any model, let alone a view model. Essentially for a tableview you need an array. If your view model contains an array then you would use it in the data source methods you have shown. It is impossible to give a more specific answer as your question is too broad.